# gitignore: Ignore everything from subfolder except files with specific extensions

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm a bit overwhelmed with the amount of gitignore related questions on stackoverflow, but couldn't find one with the same problem I currently have:

This is my file structure:

```
➜  main git:(master) ✗ tree
.
└── lib
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── sub1
    │   │   └── test.txt
    │   ├── test.md
    │   └── test.txt
    └── folder2
        ├── sub1
        │   └── test.txt
        ├── test.md
        └── test.txt

5 directories, 6 files
```

I would like to exclude the lib folder, but include every file with the extension ".txt".

This is my current .gitignore file:

```
➜  main git:(master) ✗ cat .gitignore
/lib/
!/lib/**/*.txt
```

Unfortunately, the whole lib folder is excluded and no textfile is included.

I also have tried countless of other patterns, but I end up either with the lib folder being ignored by git or a lib folder which is being included with all of its files.

It's also important to me that I don't have to specify each subfolder in my .gitignore (like `!folder1/`, `!folder2/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works:

```
lib/**/*.*
!lib/**/*.txt
```

Comment: Ugh, I think it will fail for files without extension without a comma. But that's corner case enough.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. My minimal working example actually was a little bit too simple. I have solved it by specifying ```lib/**/*``` instead of ```lib/**/*.*```. This works for me at least.